# What is the testbench process for hashing algorithms?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, hash, cryptography, steganography

Suppose that I wrote an implementation of a standard algorithm such as an MD* or a SHA*: How I know that it's correct ? Different implementations of the same algorithm must produce the same digest ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reference documents themselves contain a small number of example cases, which can be used.  (The hash of `"abc"` is in all of the reference documents, for example.)  In addition, Aaron Gifford has made a number of test cases available at http://www.adg.us/computers/sha.html.  In particular, he has tests for some of the border cases (where the text is exactly the length of a block, or one less, and a couple of other special lengths.  If your implementation calculates the correct value for all of these, there is a good chance that it is correct.

Comment: so ... only "rules of thumb" ?

Comment: @user1849534 You can't possibly test all possible input; since the length is unbound, the number of cases would be infinite.  What you need is a good set of test cases.  Between the reference documents and Aaron Gifford's site, I've got a total of 26 test cases (but not all are valid for all of the hashing algorithms).  If the test cases cover the usual limit cases, then given the nature of the algorithm, this should be enough.

Comment: we don't do the arithmetic for all the possible functions, we have the mathematical analysis for that, I was thinking about something similar for this ...

Comment: @user1849534 I would encourage good code review as well as the tests.  The mathematical analysis has been done by the people defining the protocol.  Code review should be able to verify that your code implements the exact algorithm which has been documented.  And the tests give reasonable assurance that the code review is right.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is the case. However some hash algorithms come with variations/settings, so you will need to match those if that is the case.

A good example is how an MD5 is often given to allow you to verify your download was correct. In order for this to work the MD5 hash implementation needs to produce the same result for all implementations.

Comment: I'm not aware of any. I would take a proven application and make your own test set. Of course most programming languages already have a library that can make the hashes for you.

Comment: Just take some open source software tar-ball that is provided with a MD5 sum, and make sure you get the same result. If not, your code is broken. Once you can get it right on one pacakge, try several mroe.